# Does time.h need connection to internet

Tags: c, microcontroller, time.h

I have been trying to run a c function on my computer, which gives the number of seconds elapsed since Epoch, and it seems to work fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main () {
   time_t seconds;

   seconds = time(NULL);
   printf("Number of seconds since January 1, 1970 = %ld\n", seconds);
  
   return(0);
}
```

Now, I have a micro-controller on which I try to run the same code. It always gives me time since boot of the micro-controller, and not since EPOCH (January 1, 1970). So, I am bit confused why I dont get the usual result ? Do I need connection to internet so that some server sends out the timer since EPOCH to the time.h library ?

In other words if I run this code on a computer without internet connection, will I get the time since EPOCH. If not then why ?

Comment: Your computer has a battery-backed real-time clock (RTC) which keeps a reasonable approximation of the current time (like a digital watch).

Comment: If I understand what you want is to get time of today?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with internet access. Turn internet access on you computer off and run the program... The problem is rather that your micro-controller system doesn't have a real time clock with battery

Comment: `time(NULL)` will return whatever the internal clock is at when you call it and it does not require an internet connection, however, having an internet connection helps if you want to keep the internal clock synchronized automatically. If you don't, you'll need to set the clock manually - and keep doing it every now and then when it starts drifting.

Comment: @IanAbbott : So does it mean that if I take out the battery from the computer, and then plug it in again, then it will probably loose the time since EPOCH, and probably might need internet to re-sync ?

Comment: @DarkSide77 : I wanted to get the number of seconds elapsed since EPOCH. But, now, with the answers from the thread, I have a good understanding of why I dont get the results that I am expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, time.h do not require an internet connection. On a computer it ask the OS for current time and make some conversion to return Epoch. All PC computers have a clock chip with a battery, keeping time when power is off. Most OS use Internet to get time an make sure the clock has correct time. If no internet, then the clock still gives a reasonably correct time.

On a micro-controller, there is usually no clock chip (RTC) that keeps the time when power is down. You can buy RTC to connect to the micro controller and read probably it instead of using standard time functions.

Here is an [example of real time clock](https://www.kiwi-electronics.nl/adafruit-ds1307-real-time-clock-assembled-breakout-board) to connect to a micro-controller.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have already marked your answer as accepted

Comment: Maybe try clicking the 'accept' checkmark again; it does not show up as accepted for some reason.

Comment: Many microcontrollers also have a built in RTC, but you need to configure it, and you need to design your system with a battery to maintain it.

Comment: Having a battery backed RTC, in no way solves the problem.  You also need a library that uses it.  This is part hardware and part software.  LIkewise you need to have a mechanism to set the RTC to match some time standard, otherwise you are semi-accurately wrong all of the time.

Comment: @fpiette : Sorry I did not know that. Now it is done :)